# Criar banco de dados

Tags: postgresql, windows, pgadmin3

Estou tentando criar um banco de dados no postgres mas estou recebendo a seguinte mensagem:

> ERROR: cannot set transaction read-write mode during recovery

Eu já desinstalei, limpei o registro, instalei coloquei nova senha, mas ele sempre resgata os usuários que já estavam instalados e os banco de dados anteriores

Gostaria de ter permissão para criar banco de dados ou até mesmo zerar tudo começar de novo, mas com permissão para a criação de bancos de dados.

Estou usando PGAdmin III, com Postgres 10 64bits, no Windows

Comment: Parece que você está conectado num cluster configurado como réplica somente leitura.

Comment: Já vi essa mensagem em algum canto mesmo...

Comment: Tem como eu criar um local mesmo, sem ser replica?

Comment: O padrão do postgres é ser instalado normal, sem ser replica. Conheço pouco de replicação, então não sei te dizer exatamente o que configurar para desabilitar. Como é local, porque não instala o postgres do início e depois restaura um backup do database?

Comment: Eu já desinstalei e reinstalei mas ele sempre recupera os dados anteriores,

Comment: Foi utilizada uma pasta data diferente? As configurações ficam no postgresql.conf.

Comment: A pasta foi até excluida rs